# Does it make difference in flutter app size if I use only 1 function from a plugin which provides 100 functions?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am adding a faker plugin for Flutter but only want to use it to generate fake names. Faker also provides fake phone numbers, emails, addresses, etc. So if I just user Faker plugin for generating fakes names only, what effect it will have in my app size? Will it be less as I am only using it to generate fake names?

Comment: It depends.  Dart does do dead-code elimination via tree-shaking, but it's [not well-documented](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/33920).  I'd recommend just trying it and comparing. There is [tooling to analyze app size](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/devtools/app-size) that can help.